# Include leading whitespaces in QML TextEdit

Tags: c++, qt, text, qml

I am using a QML TextArea as a text input. It seems like this TextArea automatically removes leading and trailing whitespaces. If I start the text with a couple of spaces, the cursor doesn't move. If I then type a normal character, the cursor jumps the amount of spaces typed before.

I managed to include trailing whitespaces by changing the TextOptions of the underlying QQuickTextDocument on the C++-side, but couldn't find a way to show leading whitespaces.

Is there a way to do that?

EDIT: It's really just a (very slightly styled) TextArea

```
T.TextArea {
    id: control

    padding: 6

    opacity: enabled ? 1 : 0.8
    font.pixelSize: TextStyle.font.size.regular
    color: Color.gray_09
    selectionColor: Color.cyan_066
    selectedTextColor: color
    wrapMode: TextEdit.Wrap

    InputFieldPlaceholderText {
        anchors.top:  parent.top
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.topMargin: parent.topPadding
        anchors.leftMargin: parent.leftPadding

        textBox: control
    }

    TextEditFormatter {
        id: textAreaFormatter
        Component.onCompleted: onCompleted()
    }
}
```

Which I call like this:

```
Flickable { 
    anchors.fill: parent
    flickableDirection: Flickable.VerticalFlick
    TextArea {
        id: textArea
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

For Completion: This is what the TextEditFormatter does, but not using it doesn't change the behaviour...:

```
void TextEditFormatter::onCompleted()
{
    auto document = parent()
                    ->property("textDocument")
                    .value<QQuickTextDocument *>()
                    ->textDocument();
    auto textOptions = document->defaultTextOption();

    textOptions.setFlags(QTextOption::IncludeTrailingSpaces);
    document->setDefaultTextOption(textOptions);
}
```

Comment: show your code.

Comment: I have tried the TextArea without your code and it does not eliminate spaces, but it is impossible for me to test your current code since for example TextEditFormatter is not defined.

Comment: I overlooked an important fact. I attach the TextArea to a Flickable. Without the Flickable, the whitespaces show up, but attached to it they don't. Sorry about that.